# Referencing RETURN values in sequential INSERT statements, within a transaction (in Postgres)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am attempting to insert several records across multiple tables, all in the one transaction. In this instance, its to generate some mock data. Smaller sub-sets of this insert sequence would be used in 'production'.

The records to be inserted are:

1. an 'account'
2. a 'gist'
3. a 'version' of the gist
4. several 'files', representing the actual contents of the gist version

Schema available here for reference:
https://github.com/thomasgwatson/thegistofit/tree/master/sql

My current iteration looks like this

```
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO account (email, name, password_hash)
VALUES
  (text 'HAH@YAY.COM', text 'HAH', text 'HASHHASH')
RETURNING account_id AS new_account_id;

INSERT INTO gist (account_id)
SELECT account_id from new_account_id
RETURNING gist_id AS new_gist_id;

INSERT INTO version (gist_id, title)
SELECT gist_id, 'my gist' from new_gist_id
RETURNING version_id AS new_version_id;

INSERT INTO file (langauge, file_name, content)
VALUES
  (text 'python', text 'first.py', text 'asfoasdfj'),
  (text 'python', text 'second.py', text 'ipsum asdfasdf'),
  (text 'python', text 'third.py', text 'okaoskdaoskd')
RETURNING file_id AS new_file_ids;

INSERT INTO version_file (version_id, file_id)
-- need to do the cartesian joint here
SELECT version_id, file_id from new_version_id, new_file_ids;


COMMIT;
```

I've tried a variety of ways to do this within PostgresQL, to no avail. Looking up Common Table Expressions (WITH and AS clauses) has been one main thread. However, one line from the docs might be what is sinking me:

> A fine point of the above example is that the WITH clause is attached
>   to the INSERT, not the sub-SELECT within the INSERT. This is necessary
>   because data-modifying statements are only allowed in WITH clauses
>   that are attached to the top-level statement. However, normal WITH
>   visibility rules apply, so it is possible to refer to the WITH
>   statement's output from the sub-SELECT.

from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html

Meta commentary

1. Using DataGrip as something of a linter but it's not saving me.
2. SQL error messages don't seem to help much, likely that they have a slightly different mental model to error messages I'm used to
3. I'd be more than comfortable using Knex/Node or Psycopg2/Python to abstract the transactions, INSERT statements, and to handle the data munging there. Trying to make it work with pure SQL

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I came up with a SQL statement that runs!

```
BEGIN;

with new_account as (
  INSERT INTO account (email, name, password_hash)
  VALUES
    (text 'HAH@YAY.COM', text 'HAH', text 'HASHHASH')
  RETURNING account_id
), new_gist as (
  INSERT INTO gist (account_id)
  SELECT account_id from new_account
  RETURNING gist_id
), new_version as (
  INSERT INTO version (gist_id, title)
  SELECT gist_id, 'my gist' from new_gist
  RETURNING version_id
), new_files as (
  INSERT INTO file (langauge, file_name, content)
  VALUES
    (text 'python', text 'first.py', text 'ipsum hhb'),
    (text 'python', text 'second.py', text 'ipsum iug'),
    (text 'python', text 'third.py', text 'ipsum thd')
  RETURNING file_id
)

INSERT INTO version_file (version_id, file_id)
-- yes, doing a cartesian joint here
SELECT version_id, file_id from new_version, new_files;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: `I'm not precisely sure what I changed` ... then why are you offering this as an answer to the community?

Comment: Honestly, I was documenting my process in the question and as I was about to submit, I used the (slightly simplified) query I was about to put into the post, into DataGrip to confirm the error message and... it worked.

At a broader level, I have looked multiple times across the internet, via Google, docs, Duck Duck Go, various Stack Exchanges and could not find an example of what I was trying to create. By posting it here, I hope I can save someone the hours I spent in frustration to get to this point

Comment: The move to CTEs **is** the solution. You need to consume the values returned by the `returning` clause somehow. With plain SQL you can only store them in a temporary table or pass them on by chaining CTEs